# Open any file in android - Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I want to know if it's possible to open any kind of file if the Android have the correct app...

Like i download a PSD file and the user have Photoshop reader and open it in there.

Like "Open In" in iOS?

Or i need to do it natively?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally all you neeed to do is to fire `ACTION_VIEW` Intent on that file and let system decide how to deal with it. If user got more apps to handle certain file type (i.e. more than one PDF viewer) he will be asked which one to use. All you need to care is to `catch` the exception in case there's no app for that type (otherwise your app will crash).

Answer (score 1):

Use the WebIntent plugin to launch the view application.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent/